# Testing whether a Ruby object is in fact waiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, mutex

I have a system, comprised of a BoundedQueue class, a Producer class that pushes items into a BoundedQueue object and a Consumer class that takes items out of the BoundedQueue object, the Producer and Consumer exist on separate threads. So that items aren't lost when they're pushed to a full queue I use a condition variable and a mutex to tell the Producer to wait until the queue has a space.

I need to create a test case that checks that the Producer is waiting when the queue is full, I'm not sure if I'm being ditsy or not but I just can't think of how to do this properly.

**BoundedQueue class:**

```
class BoundedQueue
 attr_reader :count
  def initialize(size)
     @mutex = Mutex.new
     @rep = Array.new(size) if size > 0
     @size = size
     @back = size-1
     @front = 0
     @count = 0
     @condvar = ConditionVariable.new
  end
 def isEmpty?
 @count == 0
 end
 def isFull?
 @count == @size
 end
 def put(item)
    @mutex.synchronize do
     if item != nil
        while isFull?
            @condvar.wait(@mutex)
        end
         @back += 1
         @back = 0 if @back >= @size
         @rep[@back] = item
         @count += 1
     end
    end
 end
 def get
    @mutex.synchronize do
     result = nil
     if (!isEmpty?)
     result = @rep[@front]
     @rep[@front] = nil
     @front += 1
     @front = 0 if @front >= @size
     @count -= 1
     @condvar.signal
     end
     result
    end
 end
end
```

**Producer class:**

```
class Producer
 def initialize(id, no_items, queue)
 @id = "Producer#{id}"
 @no_items = no_items
 @queue = queue
 end
 def produce
 while @no_items != 0
 @queue.put("Item #{@no_items} from #{@id} ")
 puts "#{@id} putting item #{@no_items} into the queue "
 @no_items -= 1
 end
 end
end
```

**Consumer class:**

```
class Consumer
 def initialize(queue)
 @queue = queue
 end
  def consume
 while !@queue.isEmpty?
 puts "#{@queue.get} consumed from the queue"
 sleep(Random.rand(10))
 end
 end
end
```

**The test case so far:**

```
require "./boundedQueue.rb"
require "./producer.rb"
require "./consumer.rb"

mutex = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new

test_queue = BoundedQueue.new(5)

puts "Creating the producer"
producerOne = Producer.new(0,7,test_queue)

puts "Creating consumer"
consumer = Consumer.new(test_queue)

puts "Creating threads"
a = Thread.new{
        producerOne.produce

}

b = Thread.new{
        consumer.consume

}


puts "Joining threads"
b.join
a.join
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current demo script?

Comment: Watch out: Your consumer might start before your producer, encounter an empty queue and therefore never process anything. (Unless you add another condition for that.)

Comment: Also afaik this kind of threading does not use multiple operating system threads in Ruby. You do get time slicing, though.

Comment: The `Fiber` class might be interesting for you.

Comment: The demo script needs to run some kind of test to show that Producer is waiting when it's supposed to, it currently does not do that, it just runs them rather than testing.

Comment: If what you want is a concurrent threaded queue, I'd recommend taking a look at the tools provided in [ruby-concurrent](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/doc/thread_pools.md), rather than trying to write your own.